# How to resolve the error for acronym file in my report?

Tags: acronyms

I have used `\usepackage{acronym}` and created an `Acr.tex` file to list all the acronyms for which the MWE is provided below. It worked fine before, but recently I am getting the following errors on compilation

> Missing $ inserted. \acro{ICT}$

and

> Command \item invalid in math mode. \acro{CSIP}$

Could anyone please suggest how to remove this error?

```
\label{page:Acronyms}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Large List of Acronyms}
\end{center}
%\section*{List of Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{ICT}$\hspace*{30pt}${Information and Communication Technology}\vspace*{0.5mm}
    \acro{CSIP}$\hspace*{24pt}${Collaborative Signal and Information Processing}
    \hspace*{15pt}
\end{acronym}
```

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error messages you get.

Comment: Please also explain the purpose of `$\hspace*{30pt}$`. My guess is that you want to achieve a list of acronyms that looks like a two column table with all long forms starting at the same horizontal position. If that's correct, you might want to take a look at a more automated solution rathen than guessing the required space and adding it manually. More automated solutions include the `acro` package in combination with one of the description templates such as `longtable` or the `glossaries-extra` package with a style such as `alttree`.